# Complex XPath searches using attributes?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have some XML which I'm trying to search:

```
<debts>
        <section id="24" description="YYYYY">
        <section id="28" description="xxx">
            <section id="31" description="xxx">
                <account accountNumber="2312323" creditorId="1" amount="1200" proposedAmount="1000" percentage="11" owner="2">
                    <foo/>
                </account>
            </section>
            <section id="32" description="xxx"/>
            <section id="33" description="xxx"/>
        </section>
        <section id="29" description="xxx">
            <section id="34" description="xxx"/>
        </section>
        <section id="30" description="xxx">
            <section id="37" description="xxx"/>
            <section id="38" description="xxx"/>
            <section id="39" description="xxx"/>
        </section>
    </section>
</debts>
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do, is find all of the account nodes that sit underneath the section YYYYY (which is quite likely not the only node at that level).  How can I do this with XPath (specifically I'm using Hpricot on Rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
/debts//section[@description='YYYYY']//account
```

http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/ has a nice tool to test xpath queries.

Comment: +1 - For the sake of completeness: This finds all account nodes within *all* section nodes that have a description of 'YYYYY'.